# Not able to run the test cases continuously using IE 11and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I'm Currently working in Automation test scripts in visual studio for IE browser version 11 using c#.
My test cases not able to run continuously one after the other.It working fine for only one test case, when it trying to attempt 2nd test cases encountering error

Specification:

1. IE browser  ver 11
2. Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver
3. C# (visual studio)

**Error:**

A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:57525/session//url. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

```
var ieoptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                ieoptions.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
                ieoptions.EnsureCleanSession = true;               

                builder.RegisterType<InternetExplorerDriver>()
                        .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "."))
                        .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(InternetExplorerOptions), ieoptions))
                        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Note: The same code and approach working for other drivers like Chrome, Chromium and Firefox

Comment: Check whether your selenium-web driver is the latest one. Make sure you are not using Driver.Quit() instead you can try to use the Driver.Close(). Make sure that firewall is not blocking the relevant port. You can check these things on your side and let us know about the results.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Yes Internet explorer is latest driver Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver (3.150.1.1), I have tried both approaches in tear down(Driver.Close and Driver.Quit). Each case successfully executed individually, problem encountered sequential run or repeated run. I don't think its firewall problem.

Comment: I can see that you have just provided the code for the IE options. Please try to show us how you are running the code one after another continuously. It may help us to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: @Deepak-MFST let me edit and update the post

Comment: After you update the post, we will try to provide you further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.